# Why am getting different answer while both are same?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-science, data-cleaning

When am trying to fetch latitude and longitude using geocode function present in ggmap library, am getting different result in both. But, when am checking the class of "dd" variable in both the cases its list, but why am not getting same output in 2nd one as 1st output. Wondering why ?

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
result <- geocode(df1$states[i],output="latlona", source = "google")
dd$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
dd$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
dd$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
```

[image]

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
result <- geocode(df1$states[i],output="latlona", source = "google")
dd$lon[i] <- result[i,1]
dd$lat[i] <- result[i,2]
dd$geoAddress[i] <- result[i,3]
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the second loop, `result` is not defined as a dataframe/matrix, thus `result[i, 1]`, where i>1 is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the second code is different than the first one. If you see, the second code would produce the same output for the first iteration as the first code does. But for the second iteration, result[i,1] is not valid because output is a data.frame with only one row. So, selecting second row (which you are doing by result[i,1] where i = 2) which does not exist gives the NA as output. You can try yourself by entering this simple code in R:

```
library(ggmap)
geocode("Delhi", output = "latlona", source = "google")[2,1]
```

The output will be `NA`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: yes @Vivek, thanks for the answer I actually sorted that out. I was about to write the solution which is same as yours. Thank you